# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /public_html/wp-includes/error-protection.php:119

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to transfer one wordpress website. After transfer I update old domain to new domain in wordpress files and database also by code. When I am trying to open website, this error is display.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /home/myserver/public_html/wp-includes/error-protection.php:119 Stack trace: #0 /home/myserver/public_html/wp-includes/error-protection.php(83): wp_is_fatal_error_handler_enabled() #1 /home/myserver/public_html/wp-settings.php(64): wp_register_fatal_error_handler() #2 /home/myserver/public_html/wp-config.php(86): require_once('/home/myserver...') #3 /home/myserver/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/myserver...') #4 /home/myserver/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/myserver...') #5 /home/myserver/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/myserver...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/myserver/public_html/wp-includes/error-protection.php on line 119

I replaced **wp-settings.php** file with latest file from wordpress. Any help will be apriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `apply_filters()` is a WordPress function. Replacing `wp-settings.php` will not work. If you copied over all the files from your old domain/server - including all core WP files, you should reinstall the core WP files. If you can get to your admin section, go to Dashboard > Updates and click the button to reinstall. If you can't get to your admin, download core WP, and then upload everything, except the `wp-content` folder to your new server.

Comment: Thank you @disinfor it worked.. +1 for this.